# compareTo: treat two nulls as equal

Tags: java, guava, comparable

I would like my compare method to work so that in the case where field1 == null in both objects, comparation would not be determined, but field2 would be checked, and so on. How to do it in the simplest way? The method below does not work well: when the fields from both objects are null, the comparison is always determined (without `Ordering.natural().NullsFirst()` I get NPE):

```
import com.google.common.collect.ComparisonChain;
import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@EqualsAndHashCode
public class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {
   
    String field1;
    Integer field2;
    String field3;   

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyClass myClass) {
        return ComparisonChain.start()
            .compare(field1, myClass.field1, Ordering.natural().nullsFirst())
            .compare(field2, myClass.field2, Ordering.natural().nullsFirst())
            .compare(field3, myClass.field3, Ordering.natural().nullsFirst())           
            .result(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the comparison would not be determined"? A comparison result can only be equal, greater than, or less than. It can't be "not determined".

Comment: not determined == equal (0), in the description of the methods used in comparisionChain they also use this expression. From ComparisonChain.compare method: "Compares two objects using a comparator, <i>if</i> the result of this comparison chain has not already been determined"

Comment: Okay, but I cannot reproduce the behaviour. It correctly outputs 0 if everything is null, and non-zero if I pass different parameters in `compare`. Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: You're right, I'm ashamed. Looking at the implementation of compareTo I forgot that null == null in Java: "if (left == right) {return 0;}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `Ordering.natural().nullsFirst()` as third parameter is the expected way.

The [documentation](https://guava.dev/releases/31.0.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html#compare(java.lang.Comparable,java.lang.Comparable)) shows it rather clearly:

> ```
> public int compareTo(Foo that) {
>   return ComparisonChain.start()
>       .compare(this.aString, that.aString)
>       .compare(this.anInt, that.anInt)
>       .compare(this.anEnum, that.anEnum, Ordering.natural().nullsLast())
>       .result();
> }
> ```

Furthermore, `ComparisonChain` is in `com.google.common.collect`, which is [annotated with `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault`](https://guava.dev/releases/31.0.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/package-summary.html), and here are the complete definition of the two compare methods used for custom objects:

> abstract ComparisonChain compare​(Comparable left, Comparable right)

And

> abstract <T extends @Nullable Object> ComparisonChain compare​(T left, T right, Comparator comparator)

The first doesn't have any parameter marked with `@Nullable` while the second, with the ordering does.

Therefore, there are no simpler way of doing what you do.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake. I forgot that null == null in Java